# OSMWidget Django form location coodinates are incorrect

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango

I have the following form field

```
point = gis_forms.PointField(widget=gis_forms.OSMWidget(
                            attrs={'map_width': 800,
                                   'map_srid': 4326,
                                   'map_height': 500,
                                   'default_lat': 49.246292,
                                   'default_lon'-123.116226,
                                   'default_zoom': 7,}))
```

The form is rendered in django as

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form|crispy }}
  <button type="submit">Submit for Review</button>
</form>
```

But when the data comes in POST the locations are incorrect.

```
def register_storage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyGeoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data=form.cleaned_data
            print(data.get('point'))
            print(data.get('point').srid)
```

The SRID is showing up as 3857 and weird default coordinates -13645232.541356523
6283123.725041488

I thought it was my django version, but it is updated to 3.1.3 due to some functionality with GDAL. But no luck.

Very lost here.

Comment: `-13645232.541356523 6283123.725041488` is the equivalent of `-123.116226 49.246292` in the SRS `3857`, so the coordinates are not wrong. See it yourself:`SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Transform('SRID=4326;POINT(-123.116226 49.246292)'::GEOMETRY,3857));` . What is exactly your problem? cheers

Comment: It is just that? why is it showing as 3857 even though I manually want the widget to use the 4326 ones? Even the documentation say that the default is 4326. Not sure why I need to transform it back..

Comment: I'm also experiencing this...can't for the life of me work out what's going on. In Django admin the coordinates are correctly displaying in 4326 (e.g. `SRID=4326;POLYGON ((0.6564331054687499 ...`) whereas if I `print(mymodelobject.geom)` I get `SRID=3857;POLYGON ((73107.017232...`

Did you ever find an answer to this @soysushi?

Comment: @Simon hey so I solved it by using the Point library to convert it as Jim mentioned. I did ```from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point ``` and then a later line down the road.
 ```user_location = Point(longitude, latitude, srid=4326)```

Comment: Hey @soysushi thanks for getting back to me. If it helps, I think I've got to the bottom of it. I posted a question similar to yours last week, and I think I finally solved it. If you're interested, you can read up on it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69084910/why-does-print-show-srid-3847-in-geodjango/69211700#69211700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must explictly define the SRID in the form's field. I'm not sure why this is the case (you'd think it would default to 4326 like the rest of Django/GeoDjango), but that's the way it seems to be. Your code should read:

```
point = gis_forms.PointField(
    srid=4326,
    widget=gis_forms.OSMWidget(
        attrs={
            "map_width": 800,
            "map_srid": 4326,
            "map_height": 500,
            "default_lat": 49.246292,
            "default_lon": -123.116226,
            "default_zoom": 7,
        }
    ),
)
```