# Why does print show SRID 3847 in Geodjango?

Tags: django, gis, geodjango

I'm developing an app using Geodjango and PostGIS. In the admin area of my site, all polygons are displayed correctly with the (default) SRID of 4326 e.g.

```
SRID=4326;POLYGON ((0.6564331054687499 52.13854550670472, 0.6289672851562499 52.08456959594681, 0.7553100585937497 52.08456959594681, 0.6564331054687499 52.13854550670472))
```

Why, when I `print` to the web server/console does the SRID show in 3857? The above admin area polygon is printed as:

```
SRID=3857;POLYGON ((73073.79904062848 6825215.129639958, 70016.31790922143 6815431.190019455, 84080.73111369385 6815431.190019455, 73073.79904062848 6825215.129639958))
```

In addition, if I render the shapes into my template with e.g. `{{geometry.polygon}}` and `{{geometry.buffer}}` both are rendered with the correct SRID of 4326.

So it seems that when doing a `print` in views.py (or elsewhere) the polygon is printed in 3857.

Note that I'm using `OSMWidget` to get user-inputted polygons. However, I'm explictly defining the map's SRID with:

```
class jobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    location = PolygonField(
        widget=OSMWidget(
            attrs={'map_width': 800,
                   'map_height': 500,
                   'map_srid': 4326,
                   'template_name': 'gis/openlayers-osm.html',
                   'default_zoom':8,
                   'default_lat': 52,
                   'default_lon': 0.5}))
```

**EDIT on 16/09/21**
After some further experimentation, I think the issue is occurring in the space between form submission and committing the data to a model.

`OSMWidget` has an argument called `map_srid` which, ostensibly, is there to allow you to specify the SRID of the coordinates returned in your form. Thus, setting `map_srid=4326` *should* return the coordinates in that format. However, it doesn't. If you print:

```
form.cleaned_data['my_geometry_field']
```

it will print in 3857, regardless of how you set `map_srid`.

Once you have committed the form's data to a model, it's converted to whatever SRID you've set on your field (by default 4326). If you do (pseudocode) `mymodel.objects.get()` and then `print(my_model_field)` you'll see your coordinates displayed in 4326 as you'd expect.

I'm therefore suspecting that there's a bug with `OSMWidget`. That or I'm completely misunderstanding how this form widget works.

Comment: SRID 3857 is in meters while 4326 is coordinate representation

Comment: I'm aware of the technical difference between the two. What I don't understand is why the admin area displays the polygon in 4326 while `print` displays the same polygon in 3857.

Comment: @Simon Are you saving the input in a model? If yes can you share your definition of it?

Comment: Hi @JohnMoutafis not quite sure what you mean. I'm taking the data from a form and, in `form_valid()` I'm carrying out some manipulation. Within `form_valid` if I call `save()` on the data and check the admin area, the form data saves in 4326. However, if I print any of the form's fields (e.g. `print(form.cleaned_data['my_geometry_field']`) it prints in 3857.

Comment: I think the issue is somewhere in the muddle between submitting the form and committing data to my model. Although I have specfied the `map_srid` in the OSMWidget as 4326, it seems like this is ignored as `print(form.cleaned_data['my_geometry_field']` prints the coordinates in 3857. However, once saved to the db, if I do `mymodel.objects.get()` and print the geometry field from that call, everything prints in 4326 as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so, answering my own question here. This has taken a lot of teeth-gnashing and I'm not sure if I'm just being dense or there's a bug of sorts. For those who need it, the official Django documentation for geospatial fields can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/forms-api/).

My understanding is that 'geospatial stuff' (using the term broadly here) in Django defaults to WGS84 (SRID 4326). Which I take to mean that, providing you don't go out of your way to override an argument/attribute, it'll default to 4326. For whatever reason, this doesn't seem to apply to GeoDjango form fields.

Whereas above in my question I specfied my geospatial field as:

```
class jobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    location = PolygonField(
        widget=OSMWidget(
            attrs={'map_width': 800,
                   'map_height': 500,
                   'map_srid': 4326,
                   'template_name': 'gis/openlayers-osm.html',
                   'default_zoom':8,
                   'default_lat': 52,
                   'default_lon': 0.5}))
```

What I should have done is explictly set the SRID argument. Thus it should be:

```
class jobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    location = PolygonField(
        srid=4326,
        widget=OSMWidget(
            attrs={'map_width': 800,
                   'map_height': 500,
                   'map_srid': 4326,
                   'template_name': 'gis/openlayers-osm.html',
                   'default_zoom':8,
                   'default_lat': 52,
                   'default_lon': 0.5}))
```

I can't see any mention in the Django documentation as to why, if you don't specify an SRID in a form's geometry field it starts spitting out coordinates in 3857. But it does for...reasons. If there is a legitimate reason why this is the case--perhaps I've missed something in the docs--then I would genuinely like to know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth, I also had this problem and was unable to rectify it by explicitly specifying the SRID argument to 4356 as mentioned above. This was using Django 4.0.

After some playing around, I had to manually convert it using the OSGEO package and add a little function to handle it like this:

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr

def convert_3857_to_4326 (coords_3857):


# create Geometry Object
point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point.AddPoint(coords_3857.coords[0], coords_3857.coords[1])
# create coordinate transformation
inSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
inSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(3857)
outSpatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
outSpatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(4326)

coordTransform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inSpatialRef, outSpatialRef)
# transform point
point.Transform(coordTransform)

# print point in EPSG 4326
print (point.GetX(), point.GetY())

return point
```

Comment: Thanks for this Dave. I was running Django 3.x (can't remember exact version number as I haven't spun up my project in a while). Sounds like my 'fix' perhaps doesn't apply to 4.x?